# Sending message with Spring Integration and ActiveMQ Artemis queue

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to send messages from a Spring Boot application using ActiveMQ Artemis and Spring Integration. In the management console I can see the address and the queue with 7 routed message count, but message count is 0 and consumers are not getting the messages:

[image]

In my producer I'm using JMS outbound adapter to send messages:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(requests())
            .transform(messageConverterQueue())
            .log()
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination(new ActiveMQQueue("requests")))
            .get();
}
```

In the logs I can see the `GenericMessage` with payload and header with no errors from the broker.

For the consumer:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlowW(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception  {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
            .transform(jsonToChunkRequestTransformer)
            .handle(chunkProcessorChunkHandler())
            .channel(replies())
            .get();
}
```

Previously I forgot to launch the consumer that's why consumer count is 0 but when it's running it turned 1.

Here is the trace:

```
 DEBUG 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.a.a.a.c.p.core.impl.ChannelImpl        : RemotingConnectionID=48a825d5 Sending packet nonblocking PACKET(SessionForceConsumerDelivery)[type=78, channelID=11, responseAsync=false, requiresResponse=false, correlationID=-1, packetObject=SessionForceConsumerDelivery, consumerID=0, sequence=14] on channelID=11
 DEBUG 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.a.a.a.c.p.core.impl.ChannelImpl        : RemotingConnectionID=48a825d5 Writing buffer for channelID=11
 INFO 19268 --- [global-threads)] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload={"jobId":348,...}, headers={id=c69469bd-8c5a-131f-ef61-cf6d86b308ca, json_resolvableType=org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest<?>, json__TypeId__=class org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1635790793335}]
 DEBUG 19268 --- [global-threads)] o.a.a.a.c.p.core.impl.ChannelImpl        : RemotingConnectionID=1362aceb Sending blocking PACKET(SessionBindingQueryMessage)[type=49, channelID=11, responseAsync=false, requiresResponse=false, correlationID=-1, packetObject=SessionBindingQueryMessage, address=requests]
 DEBUG 19268 --- [-netty-threads)] o.a.a.a.c.p.c.i.RemotingConnectionImpl   : RemotingConnectionID=48a825d5 handling packet PACKET(SessionReceiveMessage)[type=75, channelID=11, responseAsync=false, requiresResponse=false, correlationID=-1, packetObject=SessionReceiveMessage, message=ClientMessageImpl[messageID=253545, durable=false, address=replies,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[_hornetq.forced.delivery.seq=14]], consumerID=0, deliveryCount=0]
 DEBUG 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.a.a.a.c.c.impl.ClientConsumerImpl      : org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl@5d2e71f5{consumerContext=ActiveMQConsumerContext{id=0}, queueName=replies}::There was nothing on the queue, leaving it now:: returning null
 DEBUG 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.a.a.a.c.c.impl.ClientConsumerImpl      : org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl@5d2e71f5{consumerContext=ActiveMQConsumerContext{id=0}, queueName=replies}:: returning null
 TRACE 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Consumer [ActiveMQMessageConsumer[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl@5d2e71f5{consumerContext=ActiveMQConsumerContext{id=0}, queueName=replies}]] of session [ActiveMQSession->ClientSessionImpl [name=41d6e210-3b40-11ec-84ef-00ff1cbc4657, username=artemis, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@2d41bb5a, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@97a3bf2] did not receive a message
 DEBUG 19268 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.a.a.a.c.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl  : Sending commit
```

Can anyone tell me what happened to the messages? Why they're missing in the queue?

Comment: The screenshot is just for for the address. Can you provide a screenshot of the anycast `requests` queue which is bound to that address?

Comment: thanks for your return, https://imgur.com/a/qdk8mm9   https://imgur.com/a/Go6JVC5

Comment: According to https://imgur.com/a/Go6JVC5 no messages have ever been added to the queue (i.e. "Messages added" is `0`). There are also no consumers (i.e. "Consumer count" is `0`) according to https://imgur.com/a/qdk8mm9. Please add more details about your use-case and the code you're using to consume and produce messages.

Comment: In my producer i'm using jms outbound adapter to send messages: ` @Bean
 public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
     return IntegrationFlows
    .from(requests())
    .transform(messageConverterQueue())
             .log()
             .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
             .get();
 } `  in logs i can see the GenericMessage with payload and header with no errors from the broker.

Comment: Please update the actual question with these details instead of adding them in comments.

Comment: Can you, please, turn on `TRACE` logging for the `org.springframework.jms` category to be sure that `JmsTemplate` from the `Jms.outboundAdapter()` really produces JMS messages to the configured destination? You also may try the `TRACE` for the `org.apache.activemq` to see what is going on in the ActiveMQ Client. Your config doesn't look wrong so far. Although you can just use a plain `destination("requests")` on the outbound side and let the client to resolve it for you.

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: Is that the entire trace from both the producer and consumer?